# Why in so many places *p() is called a function that return a pointer instead of a function that return an address?

Tags: c

I see in so many places that the code `*p()` it refer to a *function that return a pointer*. But when coding looks clear that the function is not returning a pointer, its returning an address. The part `int *` in the function tells what is needed to handle what is coming from the function.

```
// Function returning an address
int *funcX(void){
    static int x = 5;
    return &x;
}

int *x = funcX(); // Pointer to int type
int *y(void) = &funcx; // Pointer to function that return an address to an int
```

There is a concise explanation for why is called a function that return a pointer?

Comment: *“the function is not returning a pointer, its returning an address”* – what’s the difference? And do you disagree that `int*` is a pointer type?

Comment: Pointer is something used to access something somewhere by an address. Address, well, it is only an address.

Comment: Still not seeing where the issue is here. `&x` is an `int*`. `funcX` returns an `int*`. `int*` is a pointer to `int`.

Comment: what i see `int *` in a function prototype refer to what needed to handle, you need a pointer to int to handle that, but that not mean that the function is returning a pointer. `int *` in the context of variable declaration mean that is a pointer to int.

Comment: I’m not sure where you got that idea from but it doesn’t sound correct.

Comment: *"Pointer is something used to access something somewhere by an address"* - Well, one can write `*funcX() = 2;` - by your own definition it's a pointer.

Comment: `int *funcX(void)` is a function that returns an `int*`.
`int *y(void)`: y is a variable declared to be a pointer to a function that does not accept input parameters and returns an `int*`. So `y = &funcX` is perfectly legal. I don't get what the point is.

Comment: "Address, well, it is only an address." --> Think of pointers as valid addresses.  `&x` is a _pointer_ and _address_.  `(int *) rand()` is a UB attempt to make an arbitrary value into a pointer.

Comment: *The unary `&` operator yields the address of its operand. If the operand has type ''type'', the result has type ''pointer to type''.* It is not returning *any* address, it is returning a *pointer* that when dereferenced potentially designates an object of a given type.

Comment: in your mind `int* a`, `a` as a lvalue is a pointer, `a` as a rvalue is an address?

Comment: A pointer is an *abstraction* of an address - the result of the expression `&x` is a pointer (type `int *`).

Answer (score 3):

In C, an *address* is a value of a pointer type.

For example, the unary address operator `&` yields the *address* of its operand, and expression that is of type *pointer to some_type*, where some_type is the type of the operand.

Saying that it "returns a pointer" is perhaps a bit imprecise. I've found it clearer to use the word *pointer* as an adjective, not as a noun. Thus we can have a pointer value, a pointer object, a pointer type, a pointer expression, etc. A pointer value (a value of some pointer type) is usually an address (the address of some function or object) -- except when it's a null pointer value, an invalid pointer value, or a pointer just past the end of some object.

Answer (score 0):

> Why in so many places *p() is called a function that return a pointer instead of a function that return an address?

It depends on what is being emphasized.

---

`int nabs(42)` returns -42.  `int nabs()` returns an `int`.  `int nabs()` returns an *integer*.  `int nabs()` returns an *object*.

These are different ways to describe the return as a *value*, *type*, *data class*, *data region*.

```
int nabs(int x) {
  if (x < 0) return x;
  return -x;
}
```

---

Likewise `int *funcX(void){` returns a *value* of of `&x`, a *type* of `int *` or pointer to `int`, a *data class*<sup>1</sup> as *address* or an *object*.

In C, *pointer* type has a precise meaning. *Address* does not.

> A *pointer* type may be derived from a function type or an object type, called the *referenced* type. A pointer type describes an object whose value provides a reference to an entity of the referenced type. A pointer type derived from the referenced type T is sometimes called ‘‘pointer to T’’. The construction of a pointer type from a referenced type is called ‘‘pointer type derivation’’. A pointer type is a complete object type.  C11 §6.2.5 20

---

<sup>1</sup> Not to be confused with C++ `class` which has very specific meaning.